# Setting up Response headers(security) in Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, akamai

We are delivering Angular application over Azure CDN(no web server), also there would be lots of images/videos(stored on Blob storage) that our site would be serving. How can I add security headers like X Frame options, X SSS protection, no  sniff while serving content from CDN?

Comment: Its important for us to serve website with at least these headers ✓ strict-transport-security
✓ x-content-type-options
✓ x-frame-options
✓ x-xss-protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Rules engine* and set some global rules for these. From the *Rules engine* page in the global section, select <kbd>Add Action</kbd> then <kbd>Modify Response Header</kbd>.

However, be aware that there seems to be a limit of three global actions as well as a 100 character string limit for the header value. That is pretty limiting for `Content-Security-Policy`.